# Why does onScrollListener think ListView is not created?

Tags: android, android-listview

So the error that is thrown is

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created
```

This is thrown when I uncomment the `getListView().setOnScrollListener(this);` line.

```
public class MyCategoryFragment extends ListFragment implements OnScrollListener {
    private ArrayList<Article> m_articles = new ArrayList<Article>();
    public ArticleAdapter m_artadapter;


    public MyCategoryFragment() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category, container, false);

        m_articles = manager.loadCategory(getActionBar().getTitle().toString(), 10);
        m_artadapter = new ArticleAdapter(this.getActivity(), R.layout.article_button, m_articles);
        this.setListAdapter(m_artadapter);

        //getListView().setOnScrollListener(this);
        return rootView;
    }
```

Here is the layout just so you can see it is the correct listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            />
    <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/empty"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="It's not you it's us..."/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have researched this extensively and I believe in must be something so simple but it is taking more than a day to fix this. Thanks

Comment: implement the listener in onActivityCreated() method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as the onCreateView doc stays:

creates and returns the view hierarchy associated with the fragment
so since the method does not return, you will are not able to access the ListView through getListView(). You can obtain a valid reference in the OnActivityCreate callback.

Comment: Ah cool! I spent so long looking at that! So now it doesn't crash but it doesn't do anything when it's scrolling. The Logs in onScroll aren't logged...

Comment: I am using setOnScrollListener in onActivityCreated inside of a postdelayed run statement, and I still get content view not created crash reports from some people